# Searching a product in a website - Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a website, which has a search bar. I want the user to input a string and i want to search that specific string in the website and crawl the resulting page. One was I figured out to do so was take the search url and concatenate whatever the user enter so the url is
"https://www.czone.com.pk/search.aspx?kw=" and if the user enters "ssd" i would concatenate it and that should be my start url. this is what i am trying to do here but it doesn't work so.

```
class ProductsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="gaming"
    start_urls = ["https://www.czone.com.pk/search.aspx?kw="]
    product = input("Enter the item you are looking for")
    start_urls = start_urls[0] + product

    def parse(self,response):
       pass
```

However the spider gives an error upon execution
[scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h

Is there anything i am doing wrong in the spider or is my entire approach to solve the problem is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import scrapy

class ProductsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="gaming"
    #url = "https://www.czone.com.pk/search.aspx?kw="
    product = input("Enter the item you are looking for")
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url = f'https://www.czone.com.pk/search.aspx?kw={product}',
            callback = self.parse
        )
    def parse(self,response):
       pass
```

Comment: the function "start_requests" was not recognizing "product"... so i took the line "product = input......" from where it was and put it into start_requests.... it works perfectly fine but can u please explain that when I run the code the start_requests is it self executed ? through which we then call the parse function is it so?

Comment: Although I'm not clear  about the last line, Yes , When we break the initial request then we need  start _requests function and when it executes  perfectly then the parse method works following the execution of start_requests and thus way, in parse method you will get response to scrape data.

Comment: sure but i was wondering if i have to add more links to parse how does it work now? in the prev approach start_urls was a list and u could just append to it what to do now??

Comment: Don't worry, programming means facing problem and solving that problem. When You will face that type of problem then create a new post.  Thanks